# Lens Flare with Compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm following this tutorial to create a lens flare effect with the compositor:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiD4bWvsxG4&ab_channel=SardiPax

But after playing around with it for 45 minutes, I can't seem to get it to show up with anything I do. I'm rendering on Eevee, is there something I am not considering?

[image]

Here is the suggested compositor node input:

[image]

Comment: You don't show the Image Editor here, only the 3D viewport, which won't show the effect, could you for example enable the compositor Backdrop option?

Answer (score 0):

Websites related to Lens Flare are available. Hope you find them useful.
https://artisticrender.com/creating-a-lens-flare-in-the-compositor-in-blender/
(09/2023)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, a tiny issue. Although it is ok to provide links to external sites and resources, it should only be to support your answer. It is expected for you to cover the major points in the answer itself. And then you can leave links like these if anyone is interested in all the details. Once again, thanks for the answer, but rules are rules